# how can i change the button function into a dropdown. ie,i have to get the value on dropdown

Tags: reactjs

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZfJE.jpg)here i am getting values while i am clicking button how can we change that to dropdown.can any one help me to go through it.dynamic dropdown using API

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
    const handleSelect=()=> {
        axios
        .get("https://cdndemo-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setState(response.data);
     });
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  return <div>
      <button  onClick={handleSelect}
      >
        click
      </button>

      {state?.states?.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <li key={obj.state_id}>{obj.state_name}</li>
          </div>
        );
      })}
  </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your result is an object with state property and followed by array of object. I think you need to declare setState above your handleSelect function.

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-fermat-i48fk?file=/src/App.js:51-580

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    const result = {
      states: [
        { state_id: 1, state_name: "one" },
        { state_id: 1, state_name: "two" }
      ]
    };

    setState(result);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleSelect()}>click</button>

      {state?.states?.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <li key={obj.state_id}>{obj.state_name}</li>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i have to render dynamically a dropdown

Comment: your demo doesn't show what you want, what is dynamic dropdown?